# How can I configure Feign to use only TLS1.3 and certain cyphers?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

How can I configure Feign to use only TLS1.3 and certain cyphers?

For other services I have a `RestTemplate` bean with an Apache `HttpClient`

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(final ResponseErrorHandler responseErrorHandler) {
        final var authHeaderRestTemplate = new RestTemplate(
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(getHttpClient())
        );
        authHeaderRestTemplate.setErrorHandler(responseErrorHandler);
        return authHeaderRestTemplate;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        final var sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
        final var sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslContext,
            SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS,
            SUPPORTED_CIPHERS,
            javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()
        );
        return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
    }
```

but as far as I know, Feign doesn't use the HttpClient or RestTemplate.

I would like to provide a bean which configures Feign to use the proper TLS versions and cyphers and maybe also sets an authorization header for the requests.

How can I do this?